# Decomposing a space into path connected components

Tags: general-topology

If I want to consider the family $\{U_{a}\}_{a\in J}$ of path-connected subsets of a topological space $X$, can I assume they are pairwise disjoint?  This would seem intuitively true.  I need to prove that the homotopy classes $[\{-1,1\},\{1\};X,\{x\}]$ are in bijective correspondance with the $U_{a}$'s.  I think I have an idea if I can assume that the $U_{a}$'s are disjoint!

Comment: Do you want [path _components_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components)? Otherwise, you can say something silly like, "I have $[0, 1]$, and $[0, 1)$ and are $(0, 1]$ are distinct path-connected subsets that overlap."

Comment: In the statement of the problem it says components.  I didn't read into the terminology too much.  I should have looked up the term. :S    Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, two path components are disjoint. The key point is that the union of two path-connected sets with a common point (say, $p$) is also path-connected. Indeed, one can go from any point of one set to $p$ and from there to any point of another set.

So, if two path components  had a common point, their union would be a strictly larger path-connected set, which is a contradiction.